# About Reactivecocoa dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__

Tags: ios

I can run is iOS9.1 but when running in iOS 8.4 it happened this problem. Is this means This version of ReactiveCocoa only supports iOS 9.1 ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dbtq.png)
dyld: Symbol not found: **_NSArray0**
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/12D3C7C5-E14E-4150-AD4B-4DD58230DB7B/FenYouShopping.app/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework/ReactiveCocoa (which was built for iOS 9.1)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/12D3C7C5-E14E-4150-AD4B-4DD58230DB7B/FenYouShopping.app/Frameworks/ReactiveCocoa.framework/ReactiveCocoa

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CoreFoundation framework but in case is there put it as optional